# How to mock object with constructor that takes a Class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

This is the test:

```
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.whenNew;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( {ClassUnderTesting.class} )
public class ClassUnderTestingTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldInitializeMocks() throws Exception {
        CollaboratorToBeMocked mockedCollaborator = mock(CollaboratorToBeMocked.class);

            suppress(constructor(CollaboratorToBeMocked.class, InjectedIntoCollaborator.class));

        whenNew(CollaboratorToBeMocked.class)
            .withArguments(InjectedAsTypeIntoCollaborator.class)
            .thenReturn(mockedCollaborator);

        new ClassUnderTesting().methodUnderTesting();

        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

These are the classes :

```
public class ClassUnderTesting {

    public void methodUnderTesting() {
        new CollaboratorToBeMocked(InjectedAsTypeIntoCollaborator.class);
    }

}

public class CollaboratorToBeMocked {

    public CollaboratorToBeMocked(Class<InjectedAsTypeIntoCollaborator> clazz) {
    }

    public CollaboratorToBeMocked(InjectedIntoCollaborator someCollaborator) {
    }

    public CollaboratorToBeMocked() {
    }

}

public class InjectedAsTypeIntoCollaborator {

}

public class InjectedIntoCollaborator {

}
```

This is the error :

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.TooManyConstructorsFoundException: Several matching constructors found, please specify the argument parameter types so that PowerMock can determine which method you're refering to.
Matching constructors in class CollaboratorToBeMocked were:
CollaboratorToBeMocked( InjectedIntoCollaborator.class )
CollaboratorToBeMocked( java.lang.Class.class )
```

Here comes the **question**: how can I make PowerMock figure out what constructor to look for?

*The problematic line* is the `suppress`. That is where the error comes from.

Comment: What happens when you remove the CollaboratorToBeMocked( java.lang.Class.class ) constructor?  Does it work then?

Comment: you mean, when i remove the other constructor... yes, if i remove the constructor with InjectedIntoCollaborator, it works

Answer (score 17):

Perhaps it is too late for your question. I met it today and found the solution at the following url. Basically, you need to specify your argument type like.

```
whenNew(MimeMessage.class).**withParameterTypes(MyParameterType.class)**.withArguments(isA(MyParameter.class)).thenReturn(mimeMessageMock);
```

http://groups.google.com/group/powermock/msg/347f6ef1fb34d946?pli=1

Hope it can help you. :)

Comment: This answer worked for me. I had a situation with the ResponseEntity class which has a generic T.

   public ResponseEntity(MultiValueMap<String, String> headers, HttpStatus statusCode)
   public ResponseEntity(T body, HttpStatus statusCode)
If you use the syntax:
   PowerMockito.whenNew(ResponseEntity.class).withArguments(headers, statusCode).thenReturn(responseEntity);

it doesn't work, but

PowerMockito.whenNew(ResponseEntity.class).withParameterTypes(MultiValueMap.class, HttpStatus.class).withArguments(headers, statusCode).thenReturn(responseEntity);

works

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know of PowerMock until you wrote your question, but did some reading and found this in their documentation. Still I am not really sure if that helps you:

> If the super class have several
>   constructors it's possible to tell
>   PowerMock to only suppress a specific
>   one. Let's say you have a class called
>   `ClassWithSeveralConstructors` that has
>   one constructor that takes a `String`
>   and another constructor that takes an
>   `int` as an argument and you only want
>   to suppress the `String` constructor.
>   You can do this using the 
>   `suppress(constructor(ClassWithSeveralConstructors.class, String.class));` 
>   method.

found at http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior

Isn't it the thing you wanted?

EDIT: Now I see, you've already tried suppressing. But are you sure you got the suppress call right? Isn't the first argument of `constructor()` supposed to be the class you would like to surpress the constructor in?

Comment: you're right. my supress is a mess. nevertheless, it still does not work i used `suppress(constructor(CollaboratorToBeMocked.class, InjectedIntoCollaborator.class));`

Comment: um, my test was bad. once i fixed the test class, the test went green. so, the problem is, now, the supress. might be a bug...

Comment: If you have a complete example and still fail to see the expected outcome, I should definitely file a bug report to the project.

Answer (score 0):

If using PowerMock for EasyMock you can do `PowerMock.expectNew(CollaboratorToBeMocked.class, new Class[]{InjectedIntoCollaborator.class}, ...)` where the `Class[]` is the parameter types of the constructor you're expecting to be called. This will resolve the ambiguity between the constructors.